# change select value option when you enter ID Number in javascript

Tags: javascript

Change gender when you enter SA ID number and change select value option in javascript

How to get Gender select option value automatically when you enter ID number input field javascript

Comment: Do you already have some code written that you can share, or is this more of a general question?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

```js
const setSelectGender = event => {
  const id = document.querySelector("#inputNumber").value
  document.querySelectorAll("#gendersSelect option").forEach(opt => { opt.selected = opt.value == getSexByID(id) ? true : false })
}

document.querySelector("#inputNumber")
.addEventListener("change", setSelectGender)

window.addEventListener("keyup", setSelectGender)

const getSexByID = id => {
  strlenth = (id.length-1);
  for (var i=0;i<strlenth;i++){
      if (i == 6){
        return (id[i] > 4) ? 'male' : 'female'
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="number" value="5" id="inputNumber">
  <select id="gendersSelect">
    <option value="male" >Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: No I wanna change the gender value according to users input for example if it's <5 it should return female or is above 5 then it should return male according to users input on the input field ID Number

Comment: @GeraldRaphela i updated the script - is that it ?

Comment: No that's not correct when you enter ID number consist of year of birth for example year  75 month 12 date 03 gender 3402 female and number between below 4999 is female and above 4999 is male between the 8-10 digits value will determine the gender 751203 determines the date from the date of birth date input and 3402 determines the gender if it's male or female according to users input of ID number input field so which means there's I'd number as input field type ID Number and input field date as date of birth and select as gender option values female and male

Comment: ok, now you can recognize sex by id - that's it ?

Comment: Yes can I get the values for input type date date of birth yyyy/mm/dd from the first 6 digit of the ID number from users input to generate date of birth

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <form id="form">
        <input type="number" value="5" id="inputNumber">
        <select id="gendersSelect">
          <option value="male" >Male</option>
          <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select>
      </form>

      <script>
        function setGender(event){
            let gen=this.value>5?'male':'female';
            document.getElementById("gendersSelect").value=gen;
        }
        document.getElementById("inputNumber").addEventListener('keyup',setGender);       
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Change date of birth when you enter SA ID number and change input date  in javascript

How to get input type date  automatically when you enter ID number input field javascript first 8 digits fill in date yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: Please clear your question. I don't understand

Comment: Change date of birth when you enter South African ID number and change input type date when you enter input ID number

Comment: Change date of birth when you enter South African ID number and input date in javascript

How to get date of birth automatically when you enter ID number input field javascript